# Azure QueueClient vs CloudQueue

Tags: azure, queue, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I have been using QueueClient to handle all functionality with the Storage Queue. I noticed in a few examples online that there is a CloudQueue, that has several more methods.

What is the difference between the two? Why would you use one over the other?

EDIT: I am using both Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue and Azure.Storage.Queues

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SDKs you are using?

Comment: I am using both Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue and Azure.Storage.Queues

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Storage client libraries for .NET - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage)

Azure.Storage.Queues are the v12 version of the SDK, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue is the v11 version. . .

Typically we recommend using the latest version of the SDK, and typically only one version of the SDK per application.